# Debugging vendor (Vivo) specific stacktrace

Tags: java, android

As soon as I open my Android Application, it crashes with this stack trace. I am using the bare minimum activity to launch after stripping down a lot of classes and subsystems to identify the issue, but no luck. I get the same trace.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.domain.example.debug, PID: 4171
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemService(ContextWrapper.java:803)
        at android.app.Application.getInputMethodManager(Application.java:687)
        at android.view.VivoViewImpl.switchToStylusInputIfNeed(VivoViewImpl.java:416)
        at android.view.VivoViewImpl.onVisibilityChanged(VivoViewImpl.java:405)
        at android.view.View.onVisibilityChanged(View.java:14846)
        at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:20800)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3603)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2796)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2286)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8882)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1137)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:951)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:877)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler.handleMessage(Choreographer.java:1056)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:257)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8401)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1032)
```

IndexActivity (the launched activity)

```
public class IndexActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.index);

    }
}
```

Index layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/splashLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am not even able to find the source file VivoViewImpl.java. There are no hits on google. So I wanted to know if I can "tap" some of these calls and print some values to debug further. This crash only happens on Android 11 (FunTouch OS v11) on Vivo devices. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

As there is a `getInputMethodManager` method in stack, I would try to change default keyboard app set on the device

You are getting `NullPointerException` when the framework tries to get access to `InputMethodManager`. e.g. with below method:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
            ctx.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

yet another suspicion: as `Context` is `null` in your app maybe you should use `AppCompatActivity` from `androidx`, which will carry about `ContextWrapper` also present in posted stack (with proper style set)

Comment: Actually I already had the AppCompatActivity. When stripping down the app, I changed to Activity. After changing back to AppCompatActivity, it still crashes. Also the default keyboard on the device is gboard. Maybe I will download another keyboard and check